# How to share Azure Storage Emulator among multiple development pc?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Hi I am new to azure development. We are planning to use blobs to store an images. At  development time it create local storage emulator to store blobs located on local pc. Can we make it shared so all developers working on this project can use it to store and retrieve that blobs.

I dig a lot but don't find any answer.

Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778456/accessing-azure-emulator-from-another-device

Comment: Usually storage emulator is one per PC. I would not recommend storing anything important there - many times I've lost files during Emulator upgrade. What is the use case when you'd like to have one emulator for many developers?

Answer (score 0):

hi the storage emulator just uses localDB to save the data.

see these ans 
[Windows Azure Blob Storage Emulator File Storage Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210043/windows-azure-blob-storage-emulator-file-storage-location)

[DSInit has disappeared on upgrading Azure SDK to 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980336/dsinit-has-disapeared-on-upgrading-azure-sdk-to-2-3)

you can change the save location to a sql server instance. which you can save on a server. and hence can share among others

```
WAStorageEmulator init /sqlInstance <shared sql server instance>
```

Comment: Hi, How to change location ? we are using window azure storage emulator v3.2. how to retrieve blobs from shared server currently access by http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/ path

Comment: I don't think **just** this solution will work. In the newer versions of emulator, the blobs are actually stored on the file system. You would need to change the location of those as well to some network drive which is accessible to all users.